# How do you export the original image that was inserted in a Sketch document?

Tags: image-quality, sketch-app

I've inserted a few JPEG images for backgrounds into a Sketch document, and now I want to get the full-resolution images out to use on the web. I don't want to export the JPEG into another JPEG, compressing the image yet again, but that is the only method that I can find.I don't trust Sketch's JPEG optimization to be as good as PS's since it isn't specifically a raster editor.

Is there a way to access the original images placed into the document, and "copy and paste" them out, as opposed to "export as a new JPEG"?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Make a duplicate of your Sketch file
2. Rename the file extension from .sketch to .zip
3. Extract the zip file
4. Find your image in the /images subfolder of the newly created folder

Comment: Which version of Sketch does this work with? I know they updated their file format within the last year.

Comment: @oatmealsnap just did this, works with 45.2

Comment: Great answer. I find the fact that this is necessary a particular poor UX from the Sketch folks.

Comment: Great tip! Works with 53.2,

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the images are embedded into the Sketch file and would need to be exported out individually. Unlike Illustrator or InDesign, they are not "linked" to the originals. So you would need the original files to manipulate, or you could save them out as TIFFs or some other lossless file format to maintain quality and then use Photoshop to optimize for web. However, I've never had any major complaints about Sketch's ability to export images.

Comment: This isn't really an answer :( there must be a way to do this actually

Comment: @quinn Check out the answer below. This might not have been possible with the older file format.