# Exporting multiple groups from Sketch

Tags: icon, export, sketch-app

I'm trying to export some icons I have made in Sketch. I've learnt how to export multiple layers, so each layer comes out as an individual assets (png file), but I can't find a solution for doing the same with multiple groups of layers. Is this possible?

Each icon is a group of two or three layers. The key thing here is that I would like to be able to edit the individual elements of each icon in the future, so I don't want to combine the separate layers into one.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this? Or, am I missing something and coming at this problem from the wrong angle?

To help illustrate my problem here is an image of what my setup looks like in Sketch:

[image]

What I'm trying to end up with is a folder called "icons" containing a png of the credits icon another png of the choose_folder icon and so forth.

What I'm hoping I don't need to do is select each group and export the icon individually. That would be fine for this test case with 8 icons. It is not so fine for my other project which has 20+ icons which get updated quite regularly.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any advice people can give!

Comment: Does this help, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/94997/155913 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For next time, even easier than creating slices, select the layer/group you want to export and click on the "make exportable" option on the lower right hand corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out so thought I'd post in case anyone comes across the question in the future.

Just add a slice to each group covering the area to be exported. If you use the naming convention foldername/iconname it'll even export all the selected icons into one folder. Select the ones to export from the export options at the top right of the screen. Simples!

Answer (score -3):

its simple! just convert each icons into separate artboard give proper name, then export as png or svg.

[image]